# onChange on input doesn't update state using setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have state that store array, like ['X', 'XL'] but my code code won't work I have no clue why?

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    shirtsSize: ['X', 'XL']
  }
  handleChange = index => e => {
    const { shirtsSize } = this.state
    this.setState({
      [`${shirtsSize[index]}`]: e.target.value
    })
  }

  render() {
    const { shirtsSize } = this.state
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <label htmlFor="shirtsSize">Sizes</label>
        <button>+</button>

        {shirtsSize.map((lang, index) => (
          <input
            type="text"
            name="shirtsSize"
            id="shirtsSize"
            value={lang}
            onChange={this.handleChange(index)}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Couldn't spot where is the mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With

```
this.setState({
  [`${shirtsSize[index]}`]: e.target.value
})
```

you aren't updating data in the `shirtSize` array, but createing a new key like `shortsSize[0]` and so on. You need to update the array like

```
const value = e.target.value;
this.setState(prevState => ({
  shirtsSize: [...prevState.shirtsSize.slice(0, index), value, ...prevState.shirtsSize.slice(index + 1) ]
}))
```

or simply

```
const shirtsSize = [...this.state.shirtsSize];
   shirtsSize[index] = e.target.value
   this.setState({
      shirtsSize
    })
```

Comment: @Melissa94, where do we not need to spread. `const shirtsSize = [...this.state.shirtsSize];` is needed to create a cloned copy so that the original one is not affected

Comment: but there is no different if i don't do it that way, simply  ` const {shirtsSize} = this.state`
is enough.

Comment: @Melissa94, you will find a difference when you inspect  this.state.shirtsSize in componentWillUpdate lifecycle or as a matter of fact in the childs `componentWillReceiveProps` if shirtsSize is passed as a prop to its children. Destructuring works by reference

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need smth like:

```
handleChange = index => e => {
  const {shirtsSize} = this.state
  shirtsSize[index] = e.target.value
  this.setState({shirtsSize: shirtsSize.slice()})
}
```

Comment: mutation? this is against react's 'rule'

Comment: I have changed that to avoid mutation in `setState` but in this case you will not see a big difference, as mutation is not good only in case of long running `shouldComponentUpdate` check